# Is it possible to recover a Safari saved password from a full system backup?

Tags: mac, passwords, safari

One of my family members needs to access a Safari saved password from an old machine. Currently, the files from that machine are in a Time Machine backup and a Backblaze backup.

For various reasons, we do not want to do a full system restore.

I see that there are various files related to Apple Keychain in these backups. Is it possible to recover a Safari saved password from these Keychain files? Or are there some other settings files where Safari saves passwords?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com Maybe check out the apple.stackexchange site

Comment: Try to restored the folder `~/Library/Keychains` from the TimeMachine backup.